# Search in specified date range, but only return the data with the latest date

Tags: crystal-reports

When the user searches within selected date range parameter of the report, it should only return the data with the latest decision date (throughout the whole database, not just the selected date range).

For example,  when the user search within the date range for the data below from 01/03/2016 to 01/07/2016, it should not return item 111. This is because the latest decision date of this item is 24/12/2016, which is not within the selected date range (from 01/03/2016 to 01/07/2016).

```
Item Code   Decision Date   
111          09/05/2016
111          24/12/2016
```

If the report does not have the search date range, I can group the report by item code, sort the data by decision date in desc order, and then move the data into the group header, it will always show the data with the latest decision date. But after I added the search date range parameter, it only return the latest date within the date range, not the whole database, and this is not what we wanted.

Comment: post the search query in the post

Answer (score 0):

If you're able to use subreports, pass the Item Code as a parameter to a subreport which is used to calculate the latest decision date for that Item Code. Then you can pass the results as a Shared Variable.

In order to make this work, you'll need the subreport to appear in a section before the section that needs to use it. (It can be suppressed or hidden, as long as it's above.) So for example, if you intend to suppress the details section, your subreport will need to be in a header just above that. (You can make a dummy group for this if need be.)

Comment: Thanks for the reply.I haven't used subreport before.I just created a subreport, and used the Item Code as the linked value,it is placed in the group 1 header(Group 1 is grouped by Item Code,all the data are in the details section).In the subreport, I have created formula 'shared datetimevar ddate; ddate:= maximum(Decision Date,Item Code).In the main report, I have created formula called SharedDate 'shared datetimevar ddate; ddate'.I wanted to use the shared variable in the date range selection 'SharedDate >= From and SharedDate <= To',I got the error saying SharedDate must be evaluated later.

Comment: You'll probably want to use the `WhilePrintingRecords;` keyword whenever able regarding your shared variable. (You just add it with the semicolon in a line above the rest of your formula.)

Comment: I have added whileprintingrecords in both formulas in the main and subreports, but still get the same error.